# building android-7.1.2_r36 on ubuntu 18.04 fail

Tags: android, android-source

I was building AOSP(android-7.1.2_r36,aosp_x86_64-eng) on ubuntu 18.04 with openjdk version "1.8.0_212" but it always fail in the same error.

My computer has 32G memory,so I dont think it fails because of lacking memory.

```
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer.java:18: The import java.beans.IntrospectionException cannot be resolved
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer.java:50: The method getProperties(Class<? extends Object>) from the type Representer refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer.java:51: IntrospectionException cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer.java:245: IntrospectionException cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer.java:246: The method getProperties(Class<? extends Object>) from the type PropertyUtils refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/Constructor.java:18: The import java.beans.IntrospectionException cannot be resolved
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/Constructor.java:241: The method getProperty(Class<? extends Object>, String) from the type Constructor.ConstructMapping refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/Constructor.java:322: IntrospectionException cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/Constructor.java:323: The method getProperty(Class<? extends Object>, String) from the type PropertyUtils refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/extensions/compactnotation/CompactConstructor.java:18: The import java.beans.IntrospectionException cannot be resolved
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/extensions/compactnotation/CompactConstructor.java:78: The method getProperty(Class<? extends Object>, String) from the type PropertyUtils refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/extensions/compactnotation/CompactConstructor.java:204: The method getProperty(Class<? extends Object>, String) from the type PropertyUtils refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/extensions/compactnotation/CompactConstructor.java:205: The method getSequencePropertyName(Class<?>) from the type CompactConstructor refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/extensions/compactnotation/CompactConstructor.java:218: IntrospectionException cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/extensions/compactnotation/CompactConstructor.java:219: The method getProperties(Class<? extends Object>) from the type PropertyUtils refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:18: The import java.beans.IntrospectionException cannot be resolved
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:19: The import java.beans.Introspector cannot be resolved
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:20: The import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor cannot be resolved
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:42: IntrospectionException cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:63: PropertyDescriptor cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:63: Introspector cannot be resolved
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:67: MethodProperty cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:93: IntrospectionException cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:94: The method getProperties(Class<? extends Object>, BeanAccess) from the type PropertyUtils refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:98: IntrospectionException cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:102: The method createPropertySet(Class<? extends Object>, BeanAccess) from the type PropertyUtils refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:108: IntrospectionException cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:110: The method getPropertiesMap(Class<?>, BeanAccess) from the type PropertyUtils refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:120: IntrospectionException cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:121: The method getProperty(Class<? extends Object>, String, BeanAccess) from the type PropertyUtils refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:125: IntrospectionException cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /home/duoduo/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/gen/JAVA_LIBRARIES/snakeyaml_intermediates/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/introspector/PropertyUtils.java:126: The method getPropertiesMap(Class<?>, BeanAccess) from the type PropertyUtils refers to the missing type IntrospectionException
[  0% 18/5384] target  C++: libdeqp <= external/deqp/framework/opengl/gluCallLogWrapper.cpp
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

I expect the building will go on without the error above.

Comment: Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You may try to build in docker, ie https://github.com/stucki/docker-lineageos https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-aosp, it is supposed to install all required dependencies

Comment: Thanks a lot , but is there any solution without docker?

Comment: I started to build AOSP in docker because doing so on a living OS (Arch Linux in my case) sometimes broke the process, after system updates. Not being able to reproduce a build (ie when a customer urgently asks me to fix something in ROM, after weeks/months passed since the last build) makes thing just crazy. As for your case, seems that `IntrospectionException` is not found, I guess it should be in tools.jar. Check your java setup for AOSP, check that tools.jar is not corrupt. Get the failing command line (from logs, enable verbose logging if  necessary), and investigate what goes wrong